# publish or distribute or host web project?

Tags: deployment, war, glassfish-3

I created a web application deploy on glassfish server in local host. Now i want to distribute it so that every body can use/access this application. I created .war file of my project. I do not know what have to do for publishing web application.

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your browser and go to `https://host:4848/`, port 4848 is default admin console port of glassfish server.
2. Click Applications tap for deploying your war file.